# Looking for an open source build tool that will work with SVN and .NET

Tags: .net, svn, deployment, automation

I'm looking for an open source build tool for to use with .NET solutions that are kept in an SVN repository.

Obviously, PowerShell will work, as I can just script the whole thing, but I'm looking for something a little more robust than that. I've done my searches and turned up nothing of interest.

Basically, I'm looking for a tool that:

1. Is free.
2. Can kick off .NET builds and report compiler errors.
3. Can pull the latest version from an SVN repository.
4. Can copy files out to the proper locations.
5. Has some sort of GUI, otherwise I'd just use PowerShell scripts like I said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd look into using a CI tool such as:

1. Hudson which has SVN, NAnt and MSBuild support
2. CruiseControl.NET which is a pure .NET CI tool.

Both are easy to install, configure, and run.

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

TeamCity 6.0
http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/

Not OSS though!

Answer (score 2):

TeamCity (http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/index.html), while not open source, should meet your requirements, and is free for smaller organizations/setups.

Answer (score 1):

Its obviously not open source however my build system of choice is MSBuild combined with a continuous integration tool like [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) or [CruiseControl.Net](http://ccnet.thoughtworks.com/).

- Its free
- MSBuild **is** the build system used to build .Net (understanding MSBuild helped improve my understanding of .Net in general)
- You can integrate with SVN uisng [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) in MSBuild or by using the integration in TeamCity / CruiseControl.Net
- CruiseControl.Net and TeamCity both have web interfaces, or you can use VisualStudio to perform builds as long as your MSBuild file has an extension that Visual Studio recognises (e.g. `.csproj`)